# Change time formats of all time entries in a column from hrs to AM/PM

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have input an excel sheet and there is a time column with an entry in 24hr format. Like:

**18:16**

I want to change all the time entries in this column to AM/PM format from 24hr.

**6:16 PM**

Any help will be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried yourself? Do you have code? If it's an Excel sheet, why not do it in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Use the datetime module. `.strftime("%I:%M %p")`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
s = "18:16"
print( datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M').strftime("%I:%M %p") )
```

**Output:**

```
06:16 PM
```

*Edit as per comment*

**Using Pandas**

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({"OTime": ["18:16", "19:16","20:16", "21:16"]})
print( df["OTime"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M').strftime("%I:%M %p")))
```

**Output:**

```
0    06:16 PM
1    07:16 PM
2    08:16 PM
3    09:16 PM
Name: OTime, dtype: object
```

Comment: How to apply it in the whole column? Suppose the column name is "OTime".

Comment: Updated solution using pandas